# Making select and update in one query

Tags: php, sql, select, sql-update

is there a query where I can do both querys in one?

This is the first

```
$q = "select c.id as campaignId,c.priceFactor,
              o.cid,o.bloggerPrice,o.state as state,o.customerPrice,o.id as orderId,o.listPrice,o.basicPrice
              from campaign c, orders o
              where c.id={$campaignId}
              and c.id = o.cid
              and o.state in (8,9)";
```

And this is the second

```
  foreach($orders as $order)
        {
             $listPrice      = $order->priceFactor * $order->basicPrice;

             if($order->bloggerPrice < $listPrice || $order->customerPrice < $listPrice)
             {
                $order->bloggerPrice  = $listPrice;
                $order->customerPrice = $listPrice;
             }

             $qUpdate       = "update orders set
                               listPrice = {$listPrice},bloggerPrice={$order->bloggerPrice},
                               customerPrice ={$order->customerPrice}
                               where id=$order->orderId and cid={$order->cid}";

            // $this->db->q($qUpdate);
        }
```

My question is: Can I do it the above without a PHP code just pure SQL?

Comment: What database server are you using?  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use a join right after UPDATE.  In your example, this might look something like:

```
update Orders o
inner join Campaign c on c.id = o.cid
set
    listPrice = o.priceFactor * order.basicPrice
,   bloggerPrice = case 
        when o.bloggerPrice < o.priceFactor * order.basicPrice
            then o.priceFactor * order.basicPrice
            else bloggerPrice
        end
,   listPrice = case 
        when o.customerPrice < o.priceFactor * order.basicPrice
            then o.priceFactor * order.basicPrice
            else listPrice
        end
where o.state in (8,9)
and c.id = {$campaignId}
```

Comment: Andomar - Can this be done for a single table only?
Eg: select * from table;
//Process something
update table set blah=1

Comment: @Bart J: Yes, an UPDATE can only update one table at a time.  If you want to ensure an update that spans multiple table succeeds or fails as a whole: that's what transactions are made for.