# Update and select in one query

Tags: sql, mysql

I found similar questions with correct answers. But they're a bit complicated for me.  I just want a simple basic statement.

I have:

```
string sql = "UPDATE tblPopUp 
                 SET PopUp = 'False' 
               WHERE DisplayNo = 1"
```

...and:

```
string sql1 = "SELECT Period  
                 FROM tblPopUp 
                WHERE DisplayNo = 1"
```

How can I combine them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
UPDATE tblPopUp  
SET PopUp = 'False', Period = Period  
OUTPUT DELETED.Period
WHERE DisplayNo = 1
```

For more information about OUTPUT clause please check [this post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/).

Comment: I think this only works in certain versions of SQL, not at all in MySQL, but I was able to accomplish something like this with SQL User Variables and multi-queries

Comment: this is awesome - saved me a ton of time and typing. I can now mark my records as in process by a specific instance of my load balanced application in a single statement that maintains a lock on the records... 

```

  Update top (5) [testdb_chetan].[dbo].[tbl_ngic_recordings_master]
  Set ProcessingFlag = 'InProcessByInstance',ProcessAttempts = ProcessAttempts + 1
  OUTPUT INSERTED.*
  Where ProcessingFlag = 'UnProcessed'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

There's no convention in a SQL UPDATE statement for returning data.  And vice versa -- a SELECT statement doesn't write information to a table.

If you've found questions/answers that you feel are similar to what you want, please provide links.

Comment: Morning. I know this MySQL question, but SQl Server has something of this sort. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx Dont know about MySQL...

Comment: @astander: Almost bed time here :)  No OUTPUT clause or similar that I'm aware of in MySQL - Oracle (and PostgreSQL?) has the RETURNING clause which are very similar to TSQL's OUTPUT clause.  None are ANSI, to my knowledge.

Comment: these r the links.. not sure they r the correct ones..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779786/update-table-with-a-select-query-with-a-where-clause

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562693/mysql-update-and-select-in-one-pass

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666485/making-select-and-update-in-one-query

Comment: OMG, It is Possible as per my answer try it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this (now for MySQL 5+), would be with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UPDATE tblPopUp 
             SET PopUp = 'False' 
           WHERE DisplayNo = '1'
(
SELECT Period  
             FROM tblPopUp 
            WHERE DisplayNo = '1'
)
```

Comment: This won't work and give SQL Syntax Error

Answer (score 0):

Old Q, but still in usage, for psql solution, try this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = value
WHERE condition
RETURNING column;
```