# How can i run once on time procedure?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, t-sql

I wrote multi-threads application that every single thread call a sql server procedure.. i need to protect a row from getting by more than one thread i want every row take it only with by one thread i used this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRow
    @ThreadID int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @rowID int;
    SELECT TOP (1) @rowID=[ID] FROM [TestTable] WHERE [ThreadID] = 0 (AND some other parameters)

    IF @rowID is not NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TOP (1) [TestTable] SET [CallCount] = [CallCount]+1,[ThreadID] = @ThreadID WHERE [ID] = @rowID

    --some other codes

    END
END
```

as i said i run application and then my application create 10 threads and i set threadid for taking a row by only one thread but i saw that a row called by more than 1 thread and about 4-5 threads get one row.. how could i do this the best way, i solved it by this code by i don`t like to have two same where in select and update:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRow
    @ThreadID int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @rowID int;

    UPDATE TOP (1) [TestTable] SET [CallCount] = [CallCount]+1,[ThreadID] = @ThreadID WHERE [ThreadID] = 0 (AND some other parameters)


    SELECT TOP (1) @rowID=[ID] FROM [TestTable] WHERE [ThreadID] = @ThreadID (AND some other parameters)

    IF @rowID is not NULL
    BEGIN

    --some other codes

    END
END
```

how can i do this with top code? and should i update first and then select like above code for fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? I tried to understand but I didn't get it...

Comment: @Thomas Haratyk sorry i really try to explain it.. i don`t want to select special row in more than one thread.. i wrote procedure for update theardid column of row to don`t allow other thread select it but in sametime other threads select it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or newer you may be able to [combine the `UPDATE` and `SELECT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057244/update-and-select-in-one-query) using the new [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

However I'd suggest backing up and thinking about your database schema, and whether it really fits your problem -- especially with multi-threading!

I get the impression you want to count the calls from each thread. It would work better to have each call `INSERT` a row into a simple `ThreadCallCount` table that simply has one `ThreadID` column. Every call is a new row. Later you can `Sum()` this table by `ThreadID` to get the total calls per thread. That would be simple and easy to ensure it's thread-safe.

It sounds like there's some other data you're trying to retrieve, and it's not clear how/when it gets stored. But a similar analysis -- and more, simpler tables -- might help you there.

In general: Don't feel like you need to squeeze it all in one table. With multi-threading it will help to break things into smaller pieces. Feel free to use more tables, each of which has a single, clear purpose. SQL Server is designed to handle row transactions safely and efficiently, so try to leverage that as much as possible.

Comment: tanx a lot for explain and i used `sql server 2008 r2` i gave you upvote and i like your insert method for calls count, so i have not get better answer than you and i accepted your answer, and tanx again guys (you and Coder)

Comment: Great advice Greg. Id only add that [sp_getAppLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) is also a useful method of serializing the stored procedure call. If the stored procedure is unwieldy sometimes its better to just make the other threads wait :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend *writing thead safe code* instead of doing that in stored procedure.

You did not mention your coding language, in C# one way is to wrap the code that calls this stored procedure inside `lock` block:

```
using System.Threading
...

public class ClassName {

    object syncLock = new object();
    ...

    SomeFunction(){

        lock(syncLock){

            // For example, com could be SqlCommand object that calls stored procedure
            int updatedRowCount = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: tanx i gave you upvote but really i like to solve it in sql not c#

Comment: I agree with Coder that it would be preferable to handle the thread-safety in C# (or whatever you're using). However if you prefer to do it at the SQL level -- or _have_ to, because you can't rely on the app code to implement the thread-safety for whatever reason -- I posted an answer in that vein.