# mysql: get affected row record after update

Tags: mysql

I recently use two sql queries to get row record after update like this, for example:

Step 1: I update point for user test@gmail.com

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET point=point-:point WHERE email=:email";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->bindValue(':point', 2);
$result->bindValue(':email', 'test@gmail.com');
$result->execute();
```

Step 2: I have to use another sql query to get row['point'] after it is updated

```
$sql = "SELECT point FROM user WHERE email=:email";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->bindValue(':email', 'test@gmail.com');
$result->execute();
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['point'];
```

So, my question is, is ther a shortcut for this? such as 1 single query to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update and select in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057244/update-and-select-in-one-query)

Comment: He wants the other way around, namely updating first then selecting the result afterward.

Comment: I don't think this will be possible because you can't `SELECT` something which hasn't already been updated.