# SQL Query Joining Update and Select in a single statement

Tags: sql

Need a SQL query to perform UPDATE and SELECT in a single statement.

I have two tables. 
First I need to filter the second table 
After filtering the second table, I need to update first table from the resultant filtered second table.

update statement followed by Select statement
[image: SCENARIO]

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update and select in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057244/update-and-select-in-one-query)

Comment: SQL @VR46.. This scenario is not available

Comment: please consider posting actual details rather than images stating requirements

Comment: yeah. Image means can explain scenario more clearly

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us what your database is, but this will work for SQL Server.

```
update FirstTable
set f.FirstName = case when f.FirstName = s.MiddleName then s.FN else f.FirstName end,
    f.LastName = case when f.LastName = s.MiddleName then s.FN else f.LastName end
from FirstTable f
inner join SecondTable s on f.FirstName = s.MiddleName or f.LastName = s.MiddleName
where s.FN <> 'aaa' -- Missed first time
```

I don't think it will work exactly as laid out for other RDBMs'.

EDIT: Added the where to the SQL, and the explanation that follows:

The query is of the form:

```
update table1
set col1 = x.colN
from table1 t
inner join table2 x on some condition
```

This is in two parts the update + set lines, and the from query which is a complete select statement without the actual select column list. Think of the second as being prefixed by 'select *'.

The second part (the guts of a select statement) must use the same table as the update part - FirstTable in your problem and table1 in the skeleton above. Since it selects rows from the same table as the update it knows which rows you want to update, and makes the columns in the select part  available to the update part. In the skeleton, I can then set col1 from table1 to colN from table2.

Your problem is a bit more complicated as I don't necessarily want to change FirstName or LastName. To take FirstName, I want to change FirstName to FN when FirstName = MiddleName. To do this I use a case as part of the set:

```
set f.FirstName = case when f.FirstName = s.MiddleName then s.FN else f.FirstName end
```

This says the when FirstName = MiddleName then set FirstName o FN, else set it to FirstName (in other words don't change it).

Repeat for LastName.

Hope that helps.

Comment: (FN != aaa) condition is not mentioned. Could you also explain the query too?

Comment: Yes, Simon only missed the `WHERE s.FN != 'aaa'` condition. The query first performs the join and then updates the table specified in the first row (you can use simply use the alias there: `update f`). It sets all FirstName fields to what the `case` returns, and its logic is pretty straightforward: it returns `s.FN` or `f.FirstName` depending on the condition you specified.

Comment: Edited to explain and add the missing where (d'oh!)

Comment: @simonatrcl. Thanks a lot for the explanation. Why do you use **s.Fn** after 'then'. What it does?

Comment: The syntax is **case when <condition is true> then A else b end** So if f.FirstName = s.MiddleName then take s.FN and if it isn't take f.FirstName.  It then sets FirstName to whichever of the two values it picks.

Comment: @simonatrcl Will it work for Oracle DB? If not, could you tell me, how we have to reframe it?

Comment: I haven't used Oracle for a while. That's why the first comment under the question was 'What RDBMS are you using?', and why I said that this was for SQL Server. Use the Oracle docs to see if there is an equivalent.