# mysql select and update at same time

Tags: mysql

I have a database which holds testcases for my application and I'd like to run few processes at same time. By now it looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM tests WHERE status = 0 LIMIT 20;
```

and I would like to change statuses of all these 20 records for '2' (being processed) to avoid situation where another process takes the same data for test. Is it possible in one query?

---

**EDIT:**
I want to run let's say 20 processes at same time, all of them do the same but I don't want for them to work on the same data - that's why I want to at first -> get 20 records from database with status=0, set status=2 for all 20 of them at same time -> process them with setting proper statuses for every single record from this 20 -> back to beginning

with that way I will avoid the situation when two different processes will get the same data from database

Comment: you want to update 20 records only ? and another thing, i am not able to understand

Comment: please provide the table structure and example data.
Do you want to update table and select from the same table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update and select in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057244/update-and-select-in-one-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
UPDATE 
    tests t1,
    (SELECT `id` FROM tests WHERE `status` = 0 LIMIT 0,20) t2
SET t1.`status` = 2
WHERE
    t1.`id` = t2.`id`
```