# update and select in a single query in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, analytics

Is it possible to do an update and select in a single query in MSSQL

```
  id  │ item │ Amount  
 ═════╪══════╪════════ 
  123 │ anf  │ NULL    
  123 │ sh   │ 150     
  123 │ ab   │ NULL    
  123 │ fhy  │ NULL    
  123 │ fg   │ NULL    
  124 │ ab   │ NULL    
  124 │ sh   │ 650     
  125 │ ab   │ NULL    
  125 │ sh   │ 250     
  125 │ ab   │ NULL    
  126 │ ab   │ NULL    
  126 │ gh   │ NULL    
  126 │ sh   │ 10
```

I have different ids and amount only available where item =sh
and I want the output like below in single query

```
  id  │ item │ Amount  
 ═════╪══════╪════════ 
  123 │ anf  │ 150     
  123 │ sh   │ 150     
  123 │ ab   │ 150     
  123 │ fhy  │ 150     
  123 │ fg   │ 150     
  124 │ ab   │ 650     
  124 │ sh   │ 650     
  125 │ ab   │ 250     
  125 │ sh   │ 250     
  125 │ ab   │ 250     
  126 │ ab   │ 10      
  126 │ gh   │ 10      
  126 │ sh   │ 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *window* function :

```
select *, max(amount) over (partition by id) as NewAmount
from table t
where item = 'sh';
```

For update you can use `updatable cte` :

```
with t as (
    select *, max(amount) over (partition by id) as NewAmount
    from table 
    where item = 'sh'
  )
update t
set amount = NewAmount
where amount is null;
```

Comment: I am getting NULL as answer for Max amount

Comment: @user123 it appears you have many NULLs in your amounts. How would you like SQL to treat them?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  No, you can't both change data stored in tables (UPDATE) and present data in tables (SELECT) in a single query.  You could do that in two queries, and can bundle them in a transaction to ensure that they both succeed or fail together.

Also for clarity, when you say UPDATE do you mean update the table data, or select it and then modify it for a SELECT query but do not actually store that data in tables?

Also please explain the logic for how the return set-Amount column works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I do in two queries,is it possible to get the expected result

Comment: Of course you can do that, using the `output` clause: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cd1a60f22f607649cdf36295cb329cbe

Comment: ^^^ Point taken, although not used that much.   Still waiting for an answer on the definition of UPDATE, and it seems like my question/comment about SQL version number = 2005 was deleted without notice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.item, sub.amount
FROM t
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT id, amount
FROM t
WHERE item = 'sh'
) sub
ON t.id = sub.id
```

Create a derived table that contains the amount for each id. Then join this to your main table.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to update and select in one statement, see OUTPUT clause: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/156604/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *select* the amounts, you can use window functions:

```
select id, item, max(case when item = 'sh' then amount end) over (partition by id) as Amount
from t ;
```

If you want to change then data, then you use `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(case when item = 'sh' then amount end) over (partition by id) as newAmount
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set amount = newAmount
    where amount is null;
```

I see no advantage to doing both.  If you need the update and want results returned, then issue two queries.

Answer (score 0):

Something related to your question as already been posted here, [to see it click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057244/update-and-select-in-one-query).

Example:

Update query:

```
UPDATE tblPopUp SET PopUp = 'False' WHERE DisplayNo = 1
```

Select query:

```
SELECT Period FROM tblPopUp WHERE DisplayNo = 1
```

Here is one of the answers posted:

```
UPDATE tblPopUp  
SET PopUp = 'False', Period = Period  
OUTPUT DELETED.Period
WHERE DisplayNo = 1
```

Hope it helped you.